# Does Windows Phone 8 OS support aacp?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am not able to play aac plus audio on emulator. Is this a licensing issue that is related only with the emulator or is it a general thing?

Would it work on EVERY single Windows Phone 8 installed device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's only unsupported on the emulator and real devices will play it...

Have a look here for more info about all codec info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx